# Parsed a XML file using lxml based of text string

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I have an XML file which i would like to retrive the *text* attribute of an element based on a string.

In the example below, i would like to find all subject elements which contains the string *home* (two elements). Once i get the elements, I can retrive the *text* value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<zAppointments reminder="15">
    <appointment>
        <subject>Bring pizza home</subject>
        <shape>circule</shape>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <subject>Bring hamburger home</subject>
        <shape>box</shape>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <subject>Bring banana homes</subject>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <subject>Check MS Office website for updates</subject>
  </appointment>
</zAppointments>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) XPath function:

```
//subject[contains(., 'home')]/text()
```

Demo:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as ET
>>>
>>> data = """<?xml version="1.0" ?>
... <zAppointments reminder="15">
...     <appointment>
...         <subject>Bring pizza home</subject>
...     </appointment>
...     <appointment>
...         <subject>Bring hamburger home</subject>
...     </appointment>
...     <appointment>
...         <subject>Check MS Office website for updates</subject>
...   </appointment>
... </zAppointments>"""
>>> root = ET.fromstring(data)
>>> root.xpath("//subject[contains(., 'home')]/text()")
['Bring pizza home', 'Bring hamburger home']
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. would it be possible to return the element of the tag text? since i would like to gate the value of _shape_ as well in case i find the string _home_ in my element _appointment_

Comment: @Eagle yes, you can go over elements via `//subject[contains(., 'home')]` expression. Then, get the text from the `.text` property..